# How to update collections of items in dynamo db?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following table in dynamo:

```
id | comment_ids | updated_at
1      [12, 123]   '2017-09-09'
```

when new comment has arrived (like `11`) how to update the corresponding `id` to get:

```
id | comment_ids | updated_at
1   [12, 123, 11]   '2017-09-09'
```

Comment: what is the dynamodb data type of comment_ids? Is it Set or List?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Python developer, but the API you want to use is UpdateItem.

If the data type of the attribute "comment_ids" is a Set:

```
{
    "TableName": "XXX",
    "Key": {
        "id": {
            "N": "1"
        }
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "ADD #cid :new_cid",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#cid": "comment_ids"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":new_cid": {"N": "11" }
    }
}
```

If the data type of the attribute "comment_ids" is a List:

```
{
    "TableName": "XXX",
    "Key": {
        "id": {
            "N": "1"
        }
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "SET #cid = list_append(#cid, :new_cid)",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#cid": "comment_ids"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":new_cid": {"N": "11" }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, difference between Set and Lists [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes):

**Sets**
Sets can only be of one Scalar type
Empty sets are not supported
Ordering within the set is not preserved
Each value must be unique

**Lists**
A list type attribute can store an ordered collection of values. Lists are enclosed in square brackets: [ ... ]

A list is similar to a JSON array. There are no restrictions on the data types that can be stored in a list element, and the elements in a list element do not have to be of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Use the operator or function accordingly to append to list or set.

- Operator ADD - if the data type is SET (i.e. SS)
- Function `list_append` - if the data type is LIST (i.e. L)

**Appending to List:-**

1) Define the list and use it in `ExpressionAttributeValues` (i.e. idVals)

```
idVal = [11]

response = table.update_item(
    Key={
        '#id': 1992            
    },    
    UpdateExpression="SET comment_ids = list_append(comment_ids , :idVal)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':idVal': idVal
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        '#id' : 'id'
    },
)
```

**Appending to Set:-**

1) Define the set and use it in `ExpressionAttributeValues` (i.e. idVals)

```
idVals = set([11])

response = table.update_item(
    Key={
        '#id': 1999            
    },
    UpdateExpression="ADD comment_ids :idVal",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':idVal': idVals
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        '#id' : 'id'
    },
)
```